# Accessing app running in a microk8s service from another flask app running inside k8s service

Tags: kubernetes, flask, nginx-ingress, microk8s

I have a flask app running inside a microk8s

flask app 1

```
  @app.route('/users/validate_jwt/<jwt>', methods=['POST'])
   def validate_jwt(jwt):
 
       # returns if the jwt is valid and username associated with it
       return jsonify(is_valid_jwt(jwt))
```

app 1 service definition

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 5001
      nodePort: 30001
  selector:
    app: auth-api
```

I also have ingress enabled and defined as below

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: url-shortener-ingress
  annotations:
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: ingress-nginx
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "*"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"

spec:
  rules:
    - host: url-shortener-auth.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: auth-service
                port:
                  number: 8081

    - host: url-shortener-api.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: app-service
                port:
                  number: 8082
```

I'm trying to access this from inside another flask app using requests module by passing the host and port of the service

```
AUTH_HOST = 'url-shortener-auth.com'
AUTH_PORT = '8081'

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'DELETE', 'GET'])
def root_path_operations():

    jwt = request.headers.get('Authorization').split(' ')[1]
    response  = requests.post(url=f"http://{AUTH_HOST}:{AUTH_PORT}/users/validate_jwt/{jwt}")
    _is_valid_jwt, username = (response.json())
```

but I, getting error at requests.post() inside app 2

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
> HTTPConnectionPool(host='url-shortener-auth.com', port=8081): Max
> retries exceeded with url: /users/validate_jwt/abc (Caused by
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
> 0x7f8d77f0b290>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name
> does not resolve'))

I have added entries of host to /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 url-shortener-auth.com
127.0.0.1 url-shortener-api.com

Im able to query the app 1 (authentication) from postman directly on my local but from within flas k app 2 it is giving issues. Where am i going wrong